# Problemas con keypress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pdo

Tengo un problema a la hora de insertar filas en la tabla con el evento de la tecla enter: ella funciona bien si le pongo la función con el botón, pero no quiero que me agregue filas cuando se dé click en el botón, si no quiero que me agregue las filas en la tabla cuando llene los input que en este caso serían dos el número y el monto, pero como el monto es el último input hay es donde debe tomar el valor para cuando se pulse sobre la tecla enter se agregue la fila a la tabla, ella la agrega pero no se mantiene como si se reiniciara, pero como dije antes con el botón si la agrega y funciona bien pero no lo quiero así, si no con la pulsación de la tecla enter.

**Anexo los códigos: el script**

```
 <>
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#bt_add').keypress(function(event){
             var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
             if(keycode == '13'){
            agregar(); 
            }
         });

//$('#bt_add').click(function(){
        //agregar();
    //});


    $('#bt_del').click(function(){
        eliminar(id_fila_selected);
    });


    $('#bt_delall').click(function(){
        eliminarTodasFilas();
    });


});
var cont=0;
var id_fila_selected=[];
function agregar(){
    cont++;
    var fila='<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'" onclick="seleccionar(this.id);"><td>'+cont+'</td><td>texto x defecto</td><td>0.00</td><td>confi</td></tr>';
    $('#tabla_ventas').append(fila);
    reordenar();
}

function seleccionar(id_fila){
    if($('#'+id_fila).hasClass('seleccionada')){
        $('#'+id_fila).removeClass('seleccionada');
    }
    else{
        $('#'+id_fila).addClass('seleccionada');
    }
    //2702id_fila_selected=id_fila;
    id_fila_selected.push(id_fila);
}

function eliminar(id_fila){
    /*$('#'+id_fila).remove();
    reordenar();*/
    for(var i=0; i<id_fila.length; i++){
        $('#'+id_fila[i]).remove();
    }
    reordenar();
}

function reordenar(){
    var num=1;
    $('#tabla_ventas tbody tr').each(function(){
        $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(num);
        num++;
    });
}
function eliminarTodasFilas(){
 $('#tabla_ventas tbody tr').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

}


</script>
```

**Formulario y tabla**

```
<form  name="frmContacto" method="POST">
<!-- section -->
<section>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="container">

 <?php
   $consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM hora_sorteo ORDER BY id");
   if($consulta->rowCount() > 0){
      while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

   echo "<div class='col s6 m2'>";
   echo "<input type='checkbox' name='fk_hora_sorteo[]' 
   id='chk1{$linea['id']}' value='{$linea['id']}' />";
     echo "<label class='black-text' for='chk1{$linea['id']}'>
     {$linea['hora_sorteo']}</label>";
      echo "</div>";


          }

       }

    else


       echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel yellow darken-2 center'>
         <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>¡ 
        Advertencia: No se ha encontrado ningún registro !</h5>
      </div>";

            ?>

             </div>
         </div>
      </section>




    <section>
      <div class="row">

     <?php
       $consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM animalitos ORDER BY id");
       if($consulta->rowCount() > 0){
        $i=1;
        while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        ?>  

       <div class="col s1 m1">
        <div class="chip">
            <img src="../galerias_animalitos/<?= $linea['portada']?>"  alt="imagen animalitos"/>
            <?php echo $linea['numero']; ?> <?php echo $linea['nombre']; ?>
       </div>
  </div>


     <?php
     $i++;
        }
      }
      else


          echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel yellow darken-2 center'>
          <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>¡ 
           Advertencia: No se ha encontrado ningún registro !</h5>
          </div>";

      ?>

       </div>
      </section>
    <!-- fin section -->


      <div class="row">

        <div class="col s12 m5">

             <div class="input-field col s12 m4">
             <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="nombre" autocomplete="off" required/>
             <label for="descripcion" class="black-text ">Numero Animalito:</label>
             </div>


            <div class="input-field col s12 m4">
            <input id="bt_add"  type="text" name="monto" autocomplete="off" required/>
            <label for="descripcion" class="black-text ">Monto:</label>
            </div>


      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>


           <button class="btn waves-effect blue darken-4 btn-small" type="submit" name="guardar">Generar Jugada</button>

            <button id="bt_del" class="btn waves-effect red btn-medium">Eliminar</button>

            <button id="bt_delall" class="btn waves-effect red btn-medium">Eliminar Todo</button>



           <div class="col center s12 m12">
                 <h4 class="left-align black-text">Serial:             Total:</h4>
           </div>


     </div>

    </form>


       <div class="col s12 m7">

        <div style=' overflow: auto; height: 250px;'>

             <table id="tabla_ventas" class='bordered responsive-table centered'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                         <th data-field='N&#186;'>ANIMALITO</th>
                         <th data-field='Código'>SORTEO</th>
                         <th data-field='Código'>MONTO</th>
                         <th data-field='Código'>OPERACIONES</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>


   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo he resuelto me haquedado asi

```
$('#bt_add').keypress(function(event){
             var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
             if(keycode == '13'){
            agregar(); 
            }
         });

          $( "#idFormulario" ).submit(function( event ) {
           event.preventDefault();
           });
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar la solución para que sea de utilidad para futuras personas?

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tu función al evento "submit" del formulario

```
$('#bt_add').keypress(function(event){
```

Por

```
$('#frmContacto').submit(function(event){
```

Debes colocarle una ID a tu form, puede ser el mismo que el name, lo bueno de esto es que tendrás validación con HTML5 si le colocas la propiedad required a los campos y podras enviar el formulario tanto con el botón como con la presión de "Enter" en los campos del formulario.

Comment: ya lo hice y sigue igual y ahora no añade nada

Comment: Añade tu código nuevo a verlo